Selecting by Column Names within Function
I feel like I'm losing my mind. This should be working, right?
Selecting a variable that is being piped within a dataset. I get the error that Error: object 'cyl' not found
table_fun = function(data, grouping_var){
  data %>% 
    select(grouping_var)%>%
    group_by(grouping_var)%>%
    summarise(count = n())
}

table_fun(mtcars, cyl)


Please read the text of the [tag:tidy] tag you included on your questoin. Good luck.

See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html and, in particular, https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#one-or-more-user-supplied-expressions
tidyverse functions rely on a specific style of "non-standard evaluation" which lets you do things like referring to a column of a data frame by the column name, e.g. cyl instead of mtcars$cyl. When you're using those functions within other functions, you need to take some extra care. In many simple cases, wrapping the column name in double braces will allow you to pass a function parameter and use it to select a column by that name.
table_fun <- function(data, grouping_var) {
  count(data, {{grouping_var}}, name = "count")
}

count(df, cyl, name = "count") is equivalent to df |> group_by(cyl) |> summarize(count = n()) or df |> summarize(count = n(), .by = cyl) (That last one requiring dplyr 1.1.0+ from 2023 or later.)

In the comments, OP asked about the situation where we want to refer  to a dynamically-created column with a subsequent function. See the "name injection" section here:
library(gt)
table_fun <- function(data, grouping_var, new_name) {
  count(data, {{grouping_var}}, name = "count") |>
    gt() |>
    cols_label( {{grouping_var}} := new_name)
}

table_fun(mtcars, cyl, "Cylinder")



the reference gives all needed, cheers, +1!

Okay, so if nothing has changed recently in R, I think what must be going on is that I've just been coding a lot in Python recently and my coding has improved enough that I am writing broader functions and not using the column names within the function. Thanks for the reference, I will look through that!

@James I think this answer is better than mine, and should be accepted.

FWIW, the "curly curly" operator was introduced to rlang (the engine for the "tidverse evaluation" framework) in 2019 https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/, but I think the communication around suggested best practices have gotten clearer and simpler in recent years.

Thanks! One issue I'm still having is when I pipe this to make a chart from that data, and there I've tried the three different solutions, but none seem to be working. What is the protocol when using other packages like gt? (mtcars with your code) %>% gt() %>%     cols_label({{grouping_var}} = 'Cylinder', count = "Number")

See the "name injection" section of the link and my edited answer. You have to use a different operator := when you want to dynamically set/refer to a column name.

Thanks--came across the := when reading through the links you provided but this is much clearer. So helpful!!!

So I think there is a NSE issue here.
table_fun = function(data, grouping_var){
  grouping_var <-  deparse(substitute(grouping_var))
  data %>% 
    select(data[[grouping_var]])%>%
    group_by(data[[grouping_var]])%>%
    summarise(count = n())
}




You can use ensym from rlang
library(rlang)
table_fun <- function(data, grouping_var) {
    data %>%
        select(!!ensym(grouping_var)) %>%
        group_by(!!ensym(grouping_var)) %>%
        summarise(count = n())
}

such that table_fun(mtcars, cyl) gives
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl count
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14

